# Use Java 8 compiled DTOs in lower api, calling a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jersey

I have a problem with using a lib compiled with JDK 8. I use Maven.
I need to use DTOs from this lib, I want to call a webservice over REST which provides these DTOs. 
I used Jersey with proxy to directly bind the public webservice interfaces (which was also compiled with JDK 8) 
Of course I get **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** all the time

How can I do this in general, the DTOs are just some request and result models.

Comment: This error means that you're using an older version of Java. Just don't. Use Java 8.

Comment: I am bound to Java 6 (runtime) / 7(compile) due to legacy systems at client side

Comment: Then don't use that lib, or recompile it so that it can be used in Java 6. But really, Java 6 is very old now. You should try to upgrade ASAP.

Comment: How to recompile the dependency? Do I have to manually copy the DTOs and map them with the result?